# Alignment on Google Maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to align a couple of fields on Google Maps, but it keeps growing horizontally. I want the third element to appear on the next line, but my code doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know how? Thanks

Here are the elements

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<button class="controls" id="a" type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me!</button>
<div id="b"><br/><form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = (
document.getElementById('pac-input'));
var addButton = (
document.getElementById('a'));
var form = (
document.getElementById('b'));


map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(addButton);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(form);
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. No closing tags for `</input>`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (putting them all in the same control):

```
<div id="b" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">
    <form>
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box"></input>
        <button class="controls" id="a" type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me!</button><br/>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"></input><br/>
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"></input><br/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo code snippet:

```js
// 32.715738, -117.1610838
// 40.7127837, -74.0059413
var mylatitude = 40.7127837;
var mylongitude = -74.0059413;

function GoogleMap_selected() {

    var lattitude_value = document.getElementById('slectedLat').value;
    var longitude_value = document.getElementById('slectedLon').value;

    var from = new google.maps.LatLng(mylatitude, mylongitude);
    var to = new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude_value, longitude_value);

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
        origin: from,
        destination: to,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };

    this.initialize = function () {
        var map = showMap_selected();

        directionsService.route(
        directionsRequest,

        function (response, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: map,
                    directions: response,
                    suppressMarkers: true
                });
                var leg = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                makeMarker(leg.start_location, icons.start, "title", map);
                makeMarker(leg.end_location, icons.end, 'title', map);

            } else {
                alert("Unable to retrive route");
            }

        });
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = (
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        var addButton = (
        document.getElementById('a'));
        var form = (
        document.getElementById('b'));


        // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(addButton);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(form);
    }

    function makeMarker(position, icon, title, map) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: title
        });
    }

    var icons = {
        start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        // URL
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
        // (width,height)
        new google.maps.Size(44, 32),
        // The origin point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point(22, 32)),
        end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        // URL
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
        // (width,height)
        new google.maps.Size(44, 32),
        // The origin point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor point (x,y)
        new google.maps.Point(22, 32))
    };


    var showMap_selected = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude_value, longitude_value),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("selected_map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        return map;
    };
}

function initialize() {
    var instance = new GoogleMap_selected();
    instance.initialize();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #selected_map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="panel">
    <input type="text" id="slectedLat" value="32.715738"></input>
    <input type="text" id="slectedLon" value="-117.1610838"></input>
</div>
<div id="selected_map_canvas"></div>
<div id="directions-panel"></div>
<div id="b" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">
    <form>
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box"></input>
        <button class="controls" id="a" type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me!</button><br/>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"></input><br/>
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"></input><br/>
    </form>
</div>
```